# ARC code conversion - is this NumberRef change correct?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I'm using an existing library that wasn't compiled with ARC and had the following line of code that I need to convert over when I upgraded my project:

```
CFAttributedStringSetAttribute(text, 
    CFRangeMake(position, length), 
    kCTStrokeWidthAttributeName, 
    [NSNumber numberWithFloat:[[attributes objectForKey:@"stroke"] intValue]]);
```

Compiling with ARC of course produced a few errors and I modified the code to make it more compliant. Is the code change below correct?

```
int strokeInt = [[attributes objectForKey:@"stroke"] intValue];
CFNumberRef strokeNumber = CFNumberCreate(NULL, kCFNumberSInt32Type, &strokeInt);

CFAttributedStringSetAttribute(text, 
    CFRangeMake(position, length), 
    kCTStrokeWidthAttributeName, 
    strokeNumber);
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you getting any compiler or static analyzer warnings from this code?

Comment: no warnings. but I wanted to check the semantics of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're leaking `strokeNumber` unless you are calling `CFRelease` on it. But `CFNumber` is toll-free bridged with `NSNumber`, so you can eliminate `strokeNumber` and just use a cast:

```
CFAttributedStringSetAttribute(text, 
    CFRangeMake(position, length), 
    kCTStrokeWidthAttributeName, 
    (__bridge CFNumberRef)[NSNumber numberWithFloat:[[attributes objectForKey:@"stroke"] intValue]]);
```

Furthermore, if `[attributes objectForKey:@"stroke"]` happens to already be an `NSNumber`, you can simplify to just this:

```
CFAttributedStringSetAttribute(text, 
    CFRangeMake(position, length), 
    kCTStrokeWidthAttributeName, 
    (__bridge CFNumberRef)[attributes objectForKey:@"stroke"]);
```